# How can I have dynamic model binding in ASP.NET Core webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm going to simplify the use case a lot but imagine you have a controller like this:

```
[HttpPost("process/{processorId}")]
public IActionResult Process(object data, string processorId) 
{
    var processor = _processorProvider.GetProcessor(processorId);
    var modelType = processor.GetModelType();
    //I know this doesn't work, this is what I'm missing.
    var model = (modelType)data; 
    var result = processor.process(model);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The problem with above code is that each processor is expecting its own data model which I do not know until runtime. I would like to be able to get ASP.NET framework to deserialize **and** validate the model data like normal model binding does for compile-time types.

I know there are `IModelBinder` and `IModelBinderProvider` interfaces but they just provide a custom way of binding data; the controller still needs to know what data type it can receive at compile-time.

Maybe a middleware that registers the controller on the fly? Maybe I don't need a controller at all but something more low-level but that still uses the ASP.NET framework's deserialization and model validation? I could receive the raw JSON string and deserialize it myself, but that kind of defeats the whole asp.net purpose. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write a custom model binder. Your custom binder can call into other binders once you have the type information.

Comment: @davidfowl could you elaborate as an answer how would that work? how will the base binder get invoked if there is no class to bind to in the controller?

Comment: Just a thinking, Inject processorProvider into IModelBinder then get the datatype by processorId, deserialize the data, get type and compare it with datatype , If the same model bind success.

Comment: I don't undestand why you know the model only at runtime ? I mean you know already at compile-time all kinds of model you can receive, right ? You just don't know which one you are going to receive at each API call ?

Comment: No, I will download and load dll assemblies at runtime based on the process id. so I won't know at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

First replace `data` with `proccesorId`

Next use `[FromQuery]` before `proccesorId` and `[FromForm]` before `data`

Final change route of your `Action` like this `[HttpPost("{processorId}")]`

Now everything is fine.

```
[HttpPost("{processorId}")]

public IActionResult Process([FromQuery] string processorId, [FromForm] object data)
{

    //Your code

}
```

**Note :** If you get **Error 415** use `[FromForm]` else you don't need it

**Update :**

if you want binding dynamic you can use the json for receive data and use generic method for operation

First add `Newtonsoft.Json` to your project next for validation can use `Validator.TryValidateObject(Model, new ValidationContext(Model), ICollection<ValidationResult>, true)`

**Sample Code:**

```
public IActionResult Process([FromForm] string data)
{
    ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    FirstModel?  firstModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirstModel>(data);
            
    if (firstModel != null)
    {
        if(Validator.TryValidateObject(firstModel, new ValidationContext(firstModel), results, true))
        {
            var result = new Processor<FirstModel>().Process(firstModel);

            return Ok(result);
        }
        
        return BadRequest("Model Not Valid");    
    }

    SecondModel? secondModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecondModel>(data);
            
    if (secondModel != null)
    {
        if (Validator.TryValidateObject(secondModel, new ValidationContext(secondModel), results, true))
        {
            var result = new Processor<SecondModel>().Process(secondModel);

            return Ok(result);
        }

        return BadRequest("Model Not Valid");
    }
                        
    return BadRequest("Argument Not Valid");
}
```

Comment: but what type of object will data be? how can I get a deserialized and validated object following amodel?